# Notation for the set of all measures on a given measurable space

Tags: measure-theory, notation

Let $(A, \mathscr{A})$ be a measurable space.

Is a standard notation reserved for the set of **all** measures $\mu$ defined in this space?

Something like $M(A, \mathscr{A}) := \{\mu \ : \ (A, \mathscr{A},\mu) \text{ is a measure space }\}$.

Comment: That's what I'd use...

Comment: @Yanko thanks!!

Comment: Usually it's denoted as $\mathcal{M}(X, \mathcal{F})$ if the measurable space is $(X, \mathcal{F})$. If the underlying space $X$ is clear, then just $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{F})$. However, this notation is also used for the space of all signed measures, so do make sure to mention the restriction to positive measures when applicable.

Comment: @Mathematics_Beginner very informative, thank you!

Comment: Related to what @Mathematics_Beginner wrote: Sometimes people write $\mathcal{M}(X, \mathcal{F})_+$ for the space of non-signed measures and $\mathcal{M}(X, \mathcal{F})_+^1$ for the space of probability measures.

Comment: Ah, super intuitive. I had used $M_+()$ instead of $M()_+$. I will fix this :)